# Jquery to select previous elements that arent siblings

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have DOM as below.

```
<div id="sortableWrapper">
    <div class="questionWrapper">
        <fieldset class="scheduler-border">
            <div class="form-group">
                  <select class="ddlControlType">
                    <option>opt 1</option>
                    <option>opt 2</option>
                  </select>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>   
    <div class="questionWrapper">
        <fieldset class="scheduler-border">
            <div class="form-group">
                  <select class="ddlControlType">
                    <option>opt 1</option>
                    <option>opt 2</option>
                  </select>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div> 
    <div class="questionWrapper">
        <fieldset class="scheduler-border">
            <div class="form-group">
                   <select class="ddlControlType">
                    <option>opt 1</option>
                    <option>opt 2</option>
                  </select>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>    
</div>
```

The div with class="questionWrapper" is dynamic and can be any number of them..    So lets say that i have 10 of them and im inside the 7th one.  What i want is for the Previous 6 dropdowns to be selected.  I have an event that will grab the text of the dropdown from anyone the dropdowns the you select from.

```
$(".ddlControlType").on("change", function () {
    var b = $(this).parent().find(".ddlControlType option:selected").text()
});
```

I'm aware of the prev(), prevAll() methods,  but those are for siblings of the same parent. I dont think there is any way to relate these dropdowns as siblings,  or am i wrong here.?   Basically need to select the previous 6 dropdowns if im currently selecting on the 7th one..  Any other idea.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I dont think there is any way to relate these dropdowns as siblings, or am i wrong here.?

You need to consider the anchestor **questionWrapper** siblings, because each of them has as **ddlControlType** as a child. Instead, **parent()** returns you a **parent()** and all these are not siblings.

Hence, you need to get the [.closest('.questionWrapper')](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)  and so all the previous items:

```
$(this).closest('.questionWrapper').prevAll('.questionWrapper').find(".ddlControlType").val($(this).val())
```

```js
$(".ddlControlType").on("change", function () {
  $(this).closest('.questionWrapper').prevAll('.questionWrapper').find(".ddlControlType").val($(this).val())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="sortableWrapper">
    <div class="questionWrapper">
        <fieldset class="scheduler-border">
            <div class="form-group">
                <select class="ddlControlType">
                    <option>opt 1</option>
                    <option>opt 2</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div class="questionWrapper">
        <fieldset class="scheduler-border">
            <div class="form-group">
                <select class="ddlControlType">
                    <option>opt 1</option>
                    <option>opt 2</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div class="questionWrapper">
        <fieldset class="scheduler-border">
            <div class="form-group">
                <select class="ddlControlType">
                    <option>opt 1</option>
                    <option>opt 2</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That worked like an absolute charm..!   Thanks a mill gaetanoM